# npm install angular material is stuck

Tags: angular-cli, angular15, angular-material-15

node - 16.3.2,
npm - 8.1.2,
Typescript - 4.8.2,
Angular cli - 15.0.4

I created a new Angular app. I'm able to run npm install and add required packages. However, npm install does not work only for Angular Material. When I try to run npm install on Angular Material it is stuck and nothing happens.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try `ng add @angular/material`. You can add angular martial using `ng add` command.

Comment: Thanks Mahdi! Tried that and it did not work. I found that ng add or npm install commands are automatically trying to update node for some reason and are getting stuck. So I set up a new machine with newer version of node and tried running npm install on material which worked. Then copied the material folders to node modules folder on my machine and it is working now.

Comment: you could do these in order: 1. remove `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` 2. run `npm cache clean` 3. run `npm I` with or without `--force`. You can use Yarn too. @ShankarNaru